# How to create data frame of differences in sample type values by sample ID in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, conditional-statements

I would like to create a data frame of the differences in values between two types of samples for each sample ID. The issue is some sample IDs do not have both sample types. I think I am looking for a for loop/ conditional statement but I haven't been successful in creating one

I have created some example data below:

```
ID <- c(1,3,3,4,6,6,7,7,8,8)
Type <- c('soil', 'soil', 'water','soil','soil', 'water','soil', 'water','soil', 'water')
data1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, Type))
data1$value <- runif(length(data1$ID), min=0, max=1)
head(data1)
```

The ending result would provide a data frame of the difference (water-soil) for each sample ID that has both sample types. The sample IDs the have only one data type would be recorded as NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the conditional check with `if`/`else` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(diff = if(n_distinct(Type) == 1) NA else 
                      value[Type == 'water'] - value[Type == 'soil'])
```

This returns `NA` if there is 1 unique value in `Type` or else returns the difference between the two.

---

A trick without using `if`/`else` would be to subset the difference so when there is no value it automatically returns `NA`.

```
data1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(diff = (value[Type == 'water'] - value[Type == 'soil'])[1])
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! Thank you!